# Manage Multiple Ubuntu servers

Tags: linux

I was wondering if it is possible to manage multiple ubuntu servers without using landscape, the only thing it should do is be able to run scripts through and update the system remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do what you want, there are lots of system management tools available e.g. Ansible, Chef, Salt, Puppet...